# Can't connect interact with a branch from a remote box despite being able to authenticate

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh

I have a github ssh key I've been using for some time now on my personal machine. I recently started working with AWS and have a remote server where I'd like to keep my branch up to date and host it so I can see the changes live.

I moved the key I use from my local machine to my ec2 container and changed the git remote url to be an ssh url (not http) and created an ssh config file with the following record:

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/name_of_key
```

When I call `ssh -T git@github.com` I see:

> Hi rmilejcz! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Perfect! But when I navigate to my repo and call `git pull` I see:

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

On my local machine this works but on the ec2 container it does not. The ssh config is identical, I'm using identical keys, the remote url for both git repos is identical ( `git@github.com:USERNAME/REPONAME.git` ), yet on my local machine it works perfectly and on the ec2 container I can successfully authenticate with github but cannot interact with the target branch.

I feel like I am missing something obvious but I just can't figure it out!

Comment: Use `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git pull` to maybe get some hints about what are the differences between the two machines.

Comment: Thank you! That was perfect, turns out the filesystem permissions on my repos folder needed to be changed so that I could use git without calls to sudo